# getting json dictionary values, though python and jinja

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask, jinja2

I have a dictionary in json that Im passing though into jinja using python.
The page is not working not sure if this is the correct syntax

```
{% with open(jsonobject, 'r') as f
   json_data = json.load(f)
   for a, (b,c) in json_data.items() %}
```

--------------EDIT-----------
This is a large dictionary within the json object being passed int which looks something like this

```
{"Dogs": [["spot"], 1], "Cats": [["whiskers"], 1], "fish": [["bubbles", "lefty", "tank", "goldie"], 4], "elephant": [["tiny", "spring"], 2], "zebra": [[], 1], "gazelle": [["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "gold", "silver"], 6]}
```

Comment: can you provide the error you're getting.  at the very least, you're missing a color after f.  and the for loop syntax is incorrect

Answer (score 2):

You should better decode JSON to python dictionary in view function and pass it into jinja:

```
import json

@app.route("/something")
def something():
    with open('myfile.json', 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.loads(f.read())
    return render_template("something.html", json_data=json_data)
```

something.html:

```
<dl>
{% for key, value in json_data.iteritems() %}
    <dt>{{ key|e }}</dt>
    <dd>{{ value|e }}</dd>
{% endfor %}
</dl>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to print a pretty `json` string then it might be better to prepare the actual string before passing it to `jinja`.

In the view you can do this:

```
import json

@app.route("/something")
def something():
    with open('myfile.json', 'r') as f:
        json_data = json.loads(f.read())
        formatted_json = json.dumps(
            json_data,
            sort_keys=True,
            indent=4,
            separators=(',', ': '))
    return render_template("something.html", json=formatted_json)
```

And in your `something.html` you simply print that already formatted variable:

```
{{ json }}
```

You can read more about the json string formatting in the [documentation section about "pretty printing"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html)